# Down for maintenance page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I want to create a down for maintenance page in asp.net mvc so whatever the request is it will point it to Home/Down

What router configs I need to set in global.cs file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use an [App_Offline.htm](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx) file. Simply upload an html file with this name to the route of your ASP.NET application and all requests will route to it. When you are ready to put your site back online simply delete the file. There's a [small gotcha](http://blog.kurtschindler.net/app_offline-htm-gotchas-with-asp-net-mvc/) you should be aware of when using `App_Offline.htm` file with an ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: Used this very technique on an ASP.NET site the other day - worked pretty well. However, there is another downside to this approach - if people who are already on the site are in the middle of say a transaction/purchase they too would be redirected to the `App_Offline.htm` page. A nice enhancement would be an option to allow a time threshold (i.e. 5-10 minutes) *before* it kicks so people can finish what they were doing but force all new requests to the `App_Offline.htm` page.